# How to apply sliding window with conditions in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
l = ["test1_-1", "test2_-1", "test3_-1","test4_-1", "test5_0", "test6_0", 
         "test7_1", "test8_1", "test9_1", "test10_-1", "test11_-1" ]
```

I want all the windows of size `n= 6` that contains `"_-1"` and `"_1"` if the item that contain `"_-1"` is placed before the item that contain  `"_1"`

It means that I expect the following output

```
[ ('test2_-1', 'test3_-1', 'test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1'), ('test3_-1', 'test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1', 'test8_1'), ('test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1', 'test8_1', 'test9_1'), ]
```

I tried use this function

```
from itertools import islice
def window(seq, n=6):
    it= iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

and this approach:

```
for item in(list(window(l,6))):
    if  "_-1"  in item and "_1" in item:
        print(list(window(l,6)))
```

But I don't get any output. What's wrong? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for item in window(l,6):
...   if any([elem.endswith("_-1") for elem in item]):
...     underscore_dash_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("_-1")]
...     if any([elem.endswith("_1") for elem in item]):
...       underscore_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("_1")]
...       if max(underscore_dash_indexes) < min(underscore_indexes):
...         print(item)
('test2_-1', 'test3_-1', 'test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1')
('test3_-1', 'test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1', 'test8_1')
('test4_-1', 'test5_0', 'test6_0', 'test7_1', 'test8_1', 'test9_1')
```

**Edit:***

Even shorter:

```
>>> for item in window(l,6):
...   underscore_dash_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("_-1")]
...   underscore_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("_1")]
...   if underscore_dash_indexes and  underscore_indexes  and max(underscore_dash_indexes) < min(underscore_indexes):
...     print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution using `and` and the output is: `[]`, I expected to have  all tuples that contain `"_-1"` and `"_1"` in this order